# How to append an image onto a document editor and save to ms word using syncfusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, editor, syncfusion

I have the below code which is working fine except for the last part when it has to save a word document
with the image. The word document saves successfully however the image does not display on the saved word document.

```
 var documenteditor;
    var documenteditorElement = document.getElementById("container2");

    documenteditor = documenteditorElement.ej2_instances[0].documentEditor;
    
   var imagebase64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.1);
                        imageArray.forEach(element => {
                            var img = document.createElement("img");
                            img.setAttribute("imageId", "imf");
                            img.width = '360';
                            img.height = '360';
                            img.src = element.currentSrc;
                            document.getElementById("container2").appendChild(img);
                          
                            var base64 = getBase64Image(document.getElementById("imageId"));

                            documenteditor.editor.insertImage(img.src, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                            documenteditor.editor.insertImage(imagebase64, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                            documenteditor.editor.insertImage(imagebase64, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                           
                        });

                        alpha += delta;
                        if (alpha > 1.0) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        //documenteditor.editor.insertImage(imagebase64, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                       
                        j++;
                        if (j == scannedImg.length) {
                            toastr.remove();
                            toastr.success('Image uploaded', 'Scanned Image uploaded successfully', { "timeOut": 3000 });
                            $("#btnCollapseAnswer").text("Collapse Answer");
                            $('#divQuestion').removeClass('col-lg-12');
                            $('#divQuestion').addClass('col-md-6');
                            $('#divAnswer').show();
                            collapsed = 0;
                            $("#pdfviewer")[0].ej2_instances[0].updateViewerContainer();
                            documenteditor.resize();
                        }
                    }
                    imageArray[i].src = scannedImg[i];            
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

We suspect that the issue might be with insertImage. Here we suggest you try the below code, which is an async API that will be included in our upcoming 2023 volume 1 release, expected at the end of March.

`await container.documentEditor.editor.insertImageAsync("");`

If the issue persists after using this suggested solution, we recommend you to create a ticket with Syncfusion support.

To create a support ticket:  https://support.syncfusion.com/support/tickets/create